# Aligning images and divs in various tabs without using media queries

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm writing an hybrid mobile app which is targeting only tablets. Here is the code:
[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/0s4s5to8/1/)
**`HTML:`**

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5" style="padding-top: 10%;">
                                <div class="imgOne_wrapper center-block">
                                    <img src="images/french.jpg" id="imgOne" class="img-responsive">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-7">
                                <div class="center-block">
                                    <div class="offer_orange_text center-block">
                                        <div class="offer_orange_txt_inner">french fries bonanza!</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="claims">
                                        <p class="center-block">Order dishes for Rs. 300 and get free french fries!</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="expires">This offer expires on 31 August 2015</div>
                                    <!-- <div id="share">
                                        <p>Share this offer on</p>
                                        <ul class="share-buttons">
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/Facebook.png"></a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li id="twitter">
                                                <a href="#" target="_blank" title="Tweet"><img src="images/Twitter.png"></a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li id="google">
                                                <a href="#" target="_blank" title="Share on Google+"><img src="images/Google+.png"></a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div> -->
                                    <div id="claimbtn">
                                        <a href="#" class="center-block">Claim this offer!</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**`css:`**

```
.imgOne_wrapper {
    border: 5px solid #000;
    width: 79%;
    height: 445px;
    padding: 2%;
}

#imgOne {
    height: 419px;
}

.offer_orange_text {
    width: 460px;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #B9B60A none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 16%;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

.offer_orange_txt_inner {
    width: 442px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px dashed #FFF;
    padding: 8px;
    font-family: 'times_newroman';
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 36px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#claims p{
    padding-top: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #666;
}

#expires {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #666;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}

#share {
    padding-top: 30%;
}

#share p {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #666;
}

ul.share-buttons {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.share-buttons li {
    display: inline;
}

#twitter,
#google {
    padding-left: 4%;
}

#claimbtn {
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-top: 43%;
}

#claimbtn a {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    background: #027dff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 48px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 10%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

In 7-Inch tabs, it comes as shown in screen shot:
[image: img1]
In 10-Inch tabs, it comes as shown in below screen shot:
[image: img2]
You can see that there are considerable differences between 7-Inch tab and 10-Inch tab apps. I want `image` and `offer name` to be in same positions regardless of the tab size. I don't want to use `media queries`. How can I do it?
Pixel size of 7-Inch tabs are approximately around `1024*600`.
Pixel size of 10-Inch tabs are approximately around `1280*800`.

Comment: I can't even reproduce your results: http://jsfiddle.net/0s4s5to8/
And please try to expres way more detailed what your desired result should look like and which parts are displayed wring on which resolution. (the inch size of a tablet alone has no information about its aspect ratio, pixel density or even browser or OS version)
Futhermore you tagged the question as [ios] but you are only talking about android screens...

Comment: @Daniel:You didn't add bootstrap libraries. Please check this updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0s4s5to8/1/

Comment: Please check updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply removing all your `float:left` lines nearly fixed the problem. Additionaly the `claimbtn` `padding-top` had to be removed and the `offer` box got a `max-width` to limit the div on small screens. Finally some `text-align: center` to move all text to the correct position. Here you go (and the  corresponding [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Loxos/0s4s5to8/3/)):

```
.imgOne_wrapper {
    border: 5px solid #000;
    width: 79%;
    height: 445px;
    padding: 2%;
}

#imgOne {
    height: 419px;
}

.offer_orange_text {
    max-width: 460px;
    padding: 8px;
    background: #B9B60A none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 16%;
}

.offer_orange_txt_inner {
    max-width: 442px;
    border: 1px dashed #FFF;
    padding: 8px;
    font-family: 'times_newroman';
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 36px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#claims p{
    padding-top: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #666;
    text-align:center;
}

#expires {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #666;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    text-align:center;
}

#share {
    padding-top: 30%;
}

#share p {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #666;
}

ul.share-buttons {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.share-buttons li {
    display: inline;
}

#twitter,
#google {
    padding-left: 4%;
}

#claimbtn {
    padding-right: 5%;
}

#claimbtn a {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    background: #027dff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 48px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 10%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```